# Crucible API : Query a review by changeset

Tags: atlassian-crucible

I was trying to look for a way to query the Crucible API by a specific changeset.

After looking through the API I could not find anything similar.

https://docs.atlassian.com/fisheye-crucible/latest/wadl/crucible.html

Our dev SCM is mercurial and we are trying to find a way to enforce code reviews upon pre-push . The idea is that upon a commit a mercurial hook will auto create a review on crucible and upon pre-push it will check if a review has been completed for this changeset.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's possible with this [REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/fisheye-crucible/latest/wadl/fisheye.html) by make EyeQL query? You can return "reviews" from the query and to pass csid as param, see more [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/eyeql-reference-guide-298976796.html)